# Where is the Administer menu?

Tags: 7, routes

I can't find the "Administer" menu or it's members "Content Management" or "Site Building". I've tried disabling and re-enabling the core menu module, but still cannot see these menus. This is what I can see.

[image: Drupal Menus]

Any ideas why? Or a known solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The menu structure has changed a bit from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7.

- Site building is now called structure, though modules is moved from it into it own top level menu item.
- Content management has been split up a bit and have items in content and structure.
- For administer you probably want the Configuration item.

Anyways try clicking around and I'm sure you'll find what you need.

Answer (score 6):

The administer menu was an artifact of the convoluted menu structure we had in Drupal 6.

What you see in the toolbar is basically the “Administer” menu unfolded, with “Content management” named “Content”, and so on.

The admin menu items have been slightly rearranged, but hopefully the new structure will be more intuitive to new users.

Answer (score 2):

The categories like "content management" and "site building" no longer exist, they have been replaced by the categories you see right there. These changes have been made to make the information architecture more intuitive for everyone and easier to understand for new Drupal users.

I too found myself searching for the familiar menu items when I first started using Drupal 7, but now that I've gotten used to the new structure, I must admit that (IMHO) it's more consistent and user friendly than in Drupal 6.

In other words: there is no "solution", but I'm confident that you can learn to love it.